# sql injection final issue

Tags: javascript, sql-injection, html, jquery

Working through a problem, I have managed to identify and write an SQL injection, send that injection to a site but I need to automate clicking the login button.

Is it possible (through JavaScript, html, etc) to load a webpage fill in a bunch of data fields and click a button?

I'm trying to automate something and I can do everything but click the button on the webpage.

The process is:

1. Get user data on your webpage (he will click a button to finish)
2. Send that data to a different webpage
3. Fill data fields on second webpage
4. Click a submit button on the second webpage

I am stuck on the last part.

Here is the code I have so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <script>
        function func()
        { 
          var str1 = document.getElementById("name").value;
          var str2 = "SQL ADDED EXPLOIT STRING";
          document.getElementById("name").value = str1.concat(str2);
          return true;
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form action="website.com" method="POST">
        <input name="login" id="name" value="username" />
        <button id="button" onclick="func()">press button</button>
      </form>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I think you are going to have to add more background information.  I suspect that either you are attempting to execute a more complicated attack vector than normal SQL Injection, or you are falling victim to the XY problem.  The problem is that normally SQL Injection doesn't require any form submissions at all.    Why do you feel like you have to specifically submit this form in order to make the SQL injection happen?

Comment: You need to execute JavaScript code on the **second** page that comes as a response for submitting this HTML `form`. No one knows what is going to be the result from submitting this form. Also note that when you submit the form this way,  all the current client side code (JavaScript) is going to be vanished

Comment: @razeal113 I think you are trying to reinvent the wheel here. Is there any specific reason that you want to use JavaScript here ? Web automation frameworks like Selenium can be used to do this in no time.